# Wildcard Expression For Searching

Tags: javascript, search, titanium, appcelerator

I've got a button that I want to show at the end of the search results to matter what. To do that, I've added the'filter' property to my table row. What I need is a way of getting that row called (ex. a filter match) no matter what is inputted into the search bar. I assume I'll need some form of wildcard. Did some research, and I haven't found anything that simply shows me the wildcard. Most of the results I have appear to use Regex. So, is it possible to do this?

```
search : Ti.UI.createSearchBar({
        barColor : '#666',
        height : '45dp',
        top : 0,
        showCancel : false
    }),
    filterAttribute : 'filter',
//Above is from the Table code, below is the row's code.
var buttonRow = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({
        backgroundImage : $$.components.RowBG,
        selectionStyle : 'none',
        height : '60dp',
                filter : 'I NEED THIS FILTER TO RETURN NO MATTER WHAT IS INPUTTED IN SEARCH'
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how you would do it with a Wildcard, but you can dynamically change the 'filter' attribute of your last row to be the same as the search value:

```
var data = ['oranges', 'grapes', 'lemons', 'kiwi', 'apples', 'limes'];

var rows = [];

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var row = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({
        title : data[i],
        filter : data[i]
    });
    rows.push(row);
}

var magicRow = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({
    title : 'I am always here',
    filter : 'set by code'
});
rows.push(magicRow);

var search = Titanium.UI.createSearchBar({
    barColor : '#000',
    showCancel : true,
    height : 43,
    top : 0,
});

search.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    // Set the last row filter to the current search value
    magicRow.filter = e.source.value;//
    //table.updateRow(rows.length - 1, magicRow,{animationStyle:Ti.UI.iPhone.RowAnimationStyle.NONE}); <- Should work but flickers
    // setting the data seems to work better
    table.data = rows;
});

var table = Ti.UI.createTableView({
    data : rows,
    filterAttribute : 'filter',
    search : search
});
```

This was tested on iOS with Titanium SDK  2.0.1.GA2